# onserverclick wont trigger the event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, events

Nothing works, The button doesn't trigger the event
code of button:

`<input type="button" id="regBtn" runat="server" onserverclick="RegClick"/>`

script code:

```
<script runat="server">
void RegClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    regBtn.Value += "a";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use ASP.Net Web Form, you want to use Service Control whenever posting back to server. It will go through [Life Cycle Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), and trigger the appropriate event correctly.

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server"  Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"/>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubmitButton.Text += "a";
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that it is inside another form which is used for a different purpose.. Isn't there another way?

Comment: Look like you are doing something which is not standard in ASP.Net. Please create a new question regarding what you are trying to achieve instead of what is not working.